# How to get Google to index a dynamic title in an Angular.js app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, googlebot

Google is indexing my Angular.js app's content just fine, i.e. it executes the JS, XHRs, the whole deal, but for some reason the title is not indexed properly and remains the static HTML fallback (default title set by HTML, before JS is executed).

In `index.html` I have:

`<title ng-bind="title + ' &mdash; Default Title'">Default Title</title>`

and it's set like this whenever the route changes:

```
app.run ['$location', '$rootScope', ($location, $rootScope) ->
    $rootScope.$on '$routeChangeSuccess', (event, current, previous) ->
      $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title if current.$$route
]
```

Has anyone met with this problem yet and do you have a solution for it perhaps?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Hi John! Can you explain what you mean by off-topic? I've encountered this issue using Angular.js, but I guess it can occur with any client-side generated titles, regardless of the framework. Is this what you meant by off-topic?

Comment: It seems odd that the rest of the site is being indexed properly, yet the title will not. While this is behavior of a search engine crawler, I guess the real question would be: "How early in the bootstrapping process does the title have to be bound for it to matter". I don't have a solution, I do have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For my angular site, I have this in my meta tag

`<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

This informs google that it is an ajax site and needs to recrawl my site differently. It will append `_escaped_fragment_` at the end the url and recrawl. At that point, I return pure html with title tag.

Check out this link: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Comment: This recommendation is [officially deprecated](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) as of October 2015.